# Retrieve videos by all users using the Kaltura API (media.list)

Tags: javascript, video, kaltura

I'm trying to retrieve all videos from my Kaltura account, but the API only returns videos owned by my user (admin privileges).

I set up the session as follows:

```
var PARTNER_ID = 1234;
var USER_ID = 'me@domain.com';
var SECRET = '123456';

var config = new KalturaConfiguration(PARTNER_ID);
var client = new KalturaClient(config);

client.session.start(function(success, ks) {
    // ... store the client ...
}, SECRET, USER_ID, KalturaSessionType.ADMIN, PARTNER_ID);
```

Later on, I try to retrieve all the videos on my account (including by other users).

```
var filter = new KalturaMediaEntryFilter();
var pager = new KalturaFilterPager();

client.media.listAction(function(success, results) {
    // ... handle results ...
}, filter, pager);
```

However, it only returns the videos owned by my user (USER_ID). How can I retrieve all videos instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** you need to create a session with *disableentitlement* privileges. You don't need the *USER_ID* parameter as well (set it to *null*).

```
client.session.start(function(success, ks) {
    // ... store the client ...
}, SECRET, null, KalturaSessionType.ADMIN, PARTNER_ID, null, 'disableentitlement');
```